# Update entre duas tabelas com condições

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Eu tenho uma questão em meu trabalho em relação a localizar e substituir um determinado campo, atualizando o mesmo com um valor de uma procura.

Vou dar exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho esta tabela que tem LOC_NUM_SUB e observe na imagem a cima que o 13 não tem MUN_NU, mas o LOC_NU de outro registo já tem. Preciso procurar nesta tabela o LOC_NUM baseado no LOC_NUM_SUB e preencher o MUN_NU do LOC_NO_SUB que é null.

Segue outro exemplo da mesma tabela:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesta, observe, que é diversos LOC_NU_SUB com MUN_NU null. E há um LOC_NU com o MUN_NU, preciso, de novo: preencher os MUN_NU com o valor encontrado em LOC_NU.

Tentei a seguinte instrução SQL:

```
UPDATE cepdb.log_localidade A2 SET MUN_NU = (SELECT A2.MUN_NU FROM cepdb.listacep A1 INNER JOIN cepdb.log_localidade A2 ON (A1.LOC_NUM_SUB = A2.LOC_NU) WHERE cepdb.listacep.LOC_NUM_SUB IS NOT NULL AND cepdb.log_localidade.LOC_NU = cepdb.listacep.LOC_NU)   Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'cepdb.listacep.LOC_NUM_SUB';
```

Mas me retorna erro.

Que preciso atualizar outra tabela que tem o LOC_NUM e o MUN_NU apenas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde o MUN_NU for null, que preciso colocar o código correto, relativo ao mesmo.

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro é porque o sgbd não encontrotou a coluna na subquery, pois você renomeu elas para A1 e A2 e depois utilizou o nome origianl. Tente este código :

```
UPDATE cepdb.log_localidade A2 
SET MUN_NU = (SELECT A2.MUN_NU 
FROM cepdb.listacep A1 
INNER JOIN cepdb.log_localidade A2 ON (A1.LOC_NUM_SUB = A2.LOC_NU) 
WHERE A1.LOC_NUM_SUB IS NOT NULL 
AND A2.LOC_NU = A1.LOC_NU)
```

Talvez você precise colocar um where para testar isto:

```
 Preciso procurar nesta tabela o LOC_NUM baseado no LOC_NUM_SUB e preencher o MUN_NU do LOC_NO_SUB que é null.
```